# Is it pythonic for a function to call itself in its error handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a scenario where a function calls itself during error handling if a certain condition is met. Something like:

```
def test(param):
    # code
    try:
        # attempt
    except ValueError as e:
        if (x):
            test(param+1)
```

I noticed that if I get stuck in a loop of `excepts` and try to cancel with my keyboard, I get a giant stacktrace. This doesn't seem right.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Edit:

After running this for a while, I got:

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

I am not sure it is related, but I would imagine a recursion depth issue would arise from too many recursive function calls?

Comment: There's always an alternative to recursion. Such as an explicit `while` loop.

Comment: @khelwood: ...in Python. :)

Comment: `I am not sure it is related, but I would imagine a recursion depth issue would arise from too many recursive function calls?` yes

Comment: @khelwood would you then throw a flag in there and way `while !flag` do what I am attempting to do? and if the code gets past the attempt in the `try`, then raise the flag to get out of the loop?

Comment: How many times do you want to repeat whatever you're doing if it keeps throwing an exception?

Comment: @khelwood until it succeeds. it is dependent on another api that I cannot control, so I must wait until that API has returned a true value. that is what the try is doing.

Comment: Well as you've discovered, if this is potentially many times, then recursion isn't going to work great in CPython. You can increase the recursion depth but eventually you'll hit a memory error (no tail call optimization). Just use a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to repeat your operation on failure, without using recursion.

```
def dostuff(param):
    while True:
        # code
        try:
            # attempt
        except ValueError:
            if x:
                param += 1
                continue
        break
```

This way, if `attempt` is successful, the loop will break. But if it raises a `ValueError`, and if your `x` condition (whatever that is) is true, then the body of the loop will be repeated with `param` incremented by 1.